# ClearCase 9.1.0.4 server on a Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, clearcase

I am trying to get ClearCase 9.1.0.4 Server running on a Docker container to use the container as a Jenkins build slave. I only install the Server version of ClearCase in the container so it doesn't try to install MVFS, and through device sharing I share the MVFS device on the host.

Everything seems to works fine, I can lsview, lsvob, etc. but if I try to setview I get the following error:

> cleartool: Error: Couldn't set view tag <any_view>: unknown error in MVFS
> file system

The setview command works just fine on the host. No error log is generated on the host or the container to tell me what happened.

What is even stranger is that startview works fine on the container! That command mounts the view on /view and I can cd straight into the vob that I need to work on, but setview still complains about the tag.

Anyone seen this before? Did you fix it? Is it possible to have MVFS tell me something more useful than "unknown error"? How?

And yes, I already read this.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system/files/inline-files/docker_clearcase.pdf

It doesn't help and I can't find the person who wrote it.

Comment: I wish I were not the only one out there trying to do these weird tasks...

Comment: You may want to post the DockerFile, etc., on your configuration, including the CC version/install method etc., even pastebin links should work. You would THINK creating Docker containers would be easy... But cc containers can be twitchy. If you're cutting and pasting from the PDF, just don't. I had to manually retype the examples and then fiddle with them... The PDF's have some invisible characters that confuse the heck out of Docker...

Comment: I  have tried it with RHEL 8.8 and 7.9, Centos 8.9 and 7.9. I just saw that the PDF says she used RHEL 7.6. I will try it on Monday but if that's the only base image that works this may all be a useless effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem by upgrading the Docker host to ClearCase 9.1.0.5 full installation. The Docker container now runs fine, sharing binaries and config with the host. Holy moleed, this one was worse than pulling teeth!